# Using .Call in R outside the main function

Tags: r

I was trying to analyse cor(stats) function but I stack on line containing first .Call function :

```
.Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
```

`C_cor` isn't defined before it is called, it isn't defined anywhere, how to execute above line outside the `cor` function ? Setting y to NULL, na.method to everything, and x to some dataset brings the same *object 'C_cor' not found* error, part of cor() body below :

```
> cor
    function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", 
        "kendall", "spearman")) 
{
    na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        "everything", "na.or.complete"))
    if (is.na(na.method)) 
        stop("invalid 'use' argument")
    method <- match.arg(method)
    if (is.data.frame(y)) 
        y <- as.matrix(y)
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (!is.matrix(x) && is.null(y)) 
        stop("supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'")
    if (!(is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x))) 
        stop("'x' must be numeric")
    stopifnot(is.atomic(x))
    if (!is.null(y)) {
        if (!(is.numeric(y) || is.logical(y))) 
            stop("'y' must be numeric")
        stopifnot(is.atomic(y))
    }
    Rank <- function(u) {
        if (length(u) == 0L) 
            u
        else if (is.matrix(u)) {
            if (nrow(u) > 1L) 
                apply(u, 2L, rank, na.last = "keep")
            else row(u)
        }
        else rank(u, na.last = "keep")
    }
    if (method == "pearson") 
        Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
   ...
```

**Edition example of use**

you can call C_cor like below :

```
C_cor=get("C_cor", asNamespace("stats"))  
.Call(C_cor, x=as.matrix(iris[,1:4]), y=NULL, method=1, FALSE
```

)

where method is number of method on this list :

```
c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs",   
            "everything", "na.or.complete")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C_cor` is a variable in the `stats` package that is not exported for general use. You can view it's contents with

```
 get("C_cor", asNamespace("stats"))
```

but since `environment(cor)` is `<environment: namespace:stats>`, the `cor()` function has access to those un-exported variables.

The `.Call` function is meant to run code from a compiled DLL or shared object. Perhaps read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) if you wish to track down the source code. Generally you should not try to call those functions directly yourself because if you pass in a bad/unexpected argument, you may cause a crash.